# Decode HTML character references in JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, unicode, encoding, html-entities

In my program, I have this string in entry:

```
var toto = "Lo&#195;&#175;c";
```

I would like to decode this String in order to have:

```
'LoÃ¯c'
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

These are HTML character references, also known as “HTML entities”.

To decode (or encode) them in JavaScript, it’s best to use [the *he* library](http://mths.be/he). *he* (for “HTML entities”) is a robust HTML entity encoder/decoder written in JavaScript. It supports [all standardized named character references as per HTML](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/named-character-references.html), handles [ambiguous ampersands](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands) and other edge cases [just like a browser would](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tokenization.html#tokenizing-character-references), has an extensive test suite, and — contrary to many other JavaScript solutions — *he* handles astral Unicode symbols just fine. [An online demo is available.](http://mothereff.in/html-entities)

```
var input = 'foo &#169; bar &#x2260; baz &#x1D306; qux';
var output = he.decode(input);
console.log(output);
// → 'foo © bar ≠ baz  qux'
```

(All this has nothing to do with the UTF-8 encoding, by the way. I’ve removed the tag from this question.)

Answer (score 2):

`&#195;` and `&#195;` are entities numbers. You can use this:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = toto;
console.log(element.textContent);
> "LoÃ¯c"
```

Comment: Note that this will only work in browsers, not in non-browser JavaScript environments such as Node.js. Also, it returns incorrect results in browsers that have buggy implementations of HTML entities. To ensure the results are correct, [use a library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20472318/96656).

Answer (score -3):

Check out the built-in JavaScript function `encodeURIComponent(str)` and `encodeURI(str)`.

```
var muUrl="http://www.google.com?ul=اردوان";
var myUrl2 = "http://XXXX.com/default.aspx?link=" + encodeURIComponent(myUrl);
```

In your case, this should work

Comment: How does encoding URI components help decoding HTML entities?